# subprocess.Popen throws an error when launched by Jenkins CI

Tags: python, windows, jenkins, subprocess

I'm trying to call a python script from Jenkins CI (1.509.4) which uses subprocess.Popen(), but if fails with an error. If I call that script using command prompt (Windows 7), then script works fine.
Here is a code example:

```
import os
import subprocess
params = 'svn status --no-ignore E:\\jenkins_tmp\\abc'
cwd = os.path.dirname(__file__)
print 'cwd: ' + cwd
proc = subprocess.Popen(params, cwd=cwd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''):
    print line,
proc.wait()
```

Error from Jenksins console output:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace D:\Jenkins\jobs\zzz_svn_delete_unversioned_files\workspace
[workspace] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson9055590820378012726.bat
cwd: E:\jenkins_tmp\my_utils
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\jenkins_tmp\my_utils\temp2.py", line 8, in <module>
    proc = subprocess.Popen(params, cwd=cwd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 893, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Does anyone know why this script has different behaviour being launched from Jenkins and from command prompt?

**SOLUTION:** surprisingly, it needs to use a full path to SVN, so in initial code I changed next line:

```
params = 'C:\\Program Files\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\svn.exe status --no-ignore E:\\jenkins_tmp\\abc'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are running the script yourself then you will be running it with **your** user rights, *(possibly at or near Admin)*, whereas Jenkins is running as user **anonymous** - you need to make sure that the script runs when you are logged on as **anonymous** - I suspect it might be a file/directory access rights issue.

Looking at what you are trying to do with Popen - svn status I wonder if you have considered using [pysvn](http://pysvn.tigris.org/project_downloads.html) rather than Popen - you will find it faster and more flexible.